# How to clean up app state if onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called

Tags: android

I just noticed Activity's onDestroy is not always called when Activity is destroyed. And I read android doc it is indeed the case. One thing came to my mind is how can we make sure app state is clean when this force kill happens? Consider this stupid code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 100];
MyThread thread;

class MyThread extends Thread {

    Activity activity;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        activity = MainActivity.this;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, LongRunningService.class));
    thread = new MyThread();
    thread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.activity = null;
    Log.e("Test", "onDestroy called");
}
```

}

If onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called then obviously there will be a serious memory leak. How do we handle this kind of clean up?

Comment: `onPause()` is always called and a great place to 'save' stuff. If you used an `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread` you can then cancel the `AsyncTask` during the `onPause`, which can allow you to do more as well.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is force killed, the process is dead and the memory is reclaimed. That's not a memory leak.

Generally speaking however, it's all about who retains references to things. If you only hold references to things in your activity's instance fields, then they will become unreferenced when the activity becomes unreferenced. Problem solved.

In your code, having the `Thread` hold on to an activity reference is indeed a potential memory leak if the thread isn't guaranteed to quit. You should use a weak reference, or base it on the application context not the activity context.

Comment: Thanks. Say if there is an app with an activity and a foreground service. Is it possible that the activity is killed but not the service? Or android will only acclaim resource on a per process basis? And I know that the code I provided is silly and just as an extreme example. The more general question is how to clean up app state and persist data in these force killing situations? Or we don't need to consider it at all?

Comment: It's possible the activity is destroyed (it's` onDestroy()` method is called) and not the service's `onDestroy()` method. If by "kill" you mean the unix process is killed, then no, not unless you have specified that the activity and the service run in different processes (which is not the default).